# Material Design Lite or Polymer Starter Kit?

Tags: material-design-lite

It looks like the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/) includes more components than Material Design Lite and it is available now.  Being that both are Google projects aligning with the Material Design philosophy, is there a reason why I would use MDL over the PSK?

It seems to me that you can simply remove the page.js stuff and use PSK as you would Bootstrap, jQueryUI, or any other css library/framework.

Answer (score 1):

The list of "why" people prefer one or the other might be a step towards the answer:
[(Bootstrap vs.) Polymer vs. MDL on stackshare](http://stackshare.io/stackups/bootstrap-vs-polymer-vs-material-design-lite#more)